# How to submit jobs to spark master running locally

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am using R and spark to run a simple example to test spark.

I have a spark master running locally using the following:

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

I can see the status page at http://localhost:8080/

**Code:**

```
system("spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3 --master local[*]")

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(SparkR)) # Load the library

sc <- sparkR.session(master = "local[*]")

df <- as.DataFrame(faithful)

head(df)
```

Now this runs fine when I do the following (code is saved as 'sparkcode'):

```
Rscript sparkcode.R
```

**Problem:**

But what happens is that a new spark instance is created, I want the R to use the existing master instance (should see this as a completed job http://localhost:8080/#completed-app)

P.S: using Mac OSX , spark 2.1.0 and R 3.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of things:

- If you use standalone cluster use correct url which should be `sparkR.session(master = "spark://hostname:port")`. Both hostname and port depend on the configuration but the standard port is 7077 and hostname should default to `hostname`. This is the main problem.
- Avoid using `spark-class` directly. This is what `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/` scripts are for (like `start-master.sh`). There are not crucial but handle small and tedious tasks for you.
- Standalone master is only resource manager. You have to start worker nodes as well (`start-slave*`).
- It is usually better to use `bin/spark-submit` though it shouldn't matter much here.
- `spark-csv` is no longer necessary in Spark 2.x and even if it was Spark 2.1 uses Scala 2.11 by default. Not to mention 1.0.3 is extremely old (like Spark 1.3 or so).